# Group rows into its related item. [Laravel]

Tags: mysql, laravel

Basically, I want to group all the related rows to its "main" row. (Sorry if a explain it roughly, I pretty much suck in MySQL)

I have these three tables

users

```
| id | user |
|----|------|
| 1  | John |
| 2  | Jane |
```

files

```
| id |    name  |
|----|----------|
| 1  |  Recipes |
| 2  | Calendar |
| 3  | Contacts |
```

file_user

```
| user_id | file_id |
|---------|---------|
|    1    |    1    |
|    1    |    2    |
|    2    |    3    |
```

And I need to obtain this result:

```
{
  {
    'user': 'John',
    'files': {
      'Recipes', 
      'Calendar'
    }
  },{
    'user': 'Jane',
    'files': {
      'Contacts'
    }
  }
}
```

I've done something like this

```
table('users')
  ->join('file_user', 'user.id', '=', 'file_user.user_id')
  ->join('files', 'file_user', '=', 'files.id')
```

It doesn't work, I get somethig like (just selecting the files)

```
{
  {
    'Recipes'
  },
  {
    'Calendar'
  },
  {
    'Contacts'
  }
}
```

I hope you understand me and be able to give me a hint.

Comment: Please read something about laravels way to handle many to many relationships and pivot tables http://laraveldaily.com/pivot-tables-and-many-to-many-relationships/

Comment: you can do it using php combine user-file result

Answer (score 0):

Well, assuming you are using Eloquent relationships and the `files` in the json is actually an array:

```
$users = User::with('files')->get();

$data = $users->map(function ($user) {
    return [
        'user' => $user->user, 
        'files' => $user->files->pluck('name')
    ];
});
```